# Function that's domain and co-domain are in different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning about linear algebra and was wondering if a function:

$$f : F^n \to F^m$$

where $n \neq m$, is possible. If so, what branch of mathematics studies this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure I understood. It seems to be very elementary question.

I assume $F$ is a field. It is certainly possible, and you come across it on daily basis in many different branches of mathematics.

E.g. in analysis $F=\mathbb{R}$ then $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined
$$
f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x).
$$

*Note plot $(\cos x, \sin x)$ (e.g. use [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)), it might help you with the intuition why we use such functions.*

Or in linear algebra it might look more like this $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$

$$
f(x,y) = (x, y, xy).
$$

It might be hard to tell, which example falls to which branch. Linear algebra studies objects with *linear* behavior, in terms of functions

- $f$ is *linear* iff $f(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$ for $x,y$ from some vector space and $\alpha, \beta$ from the field you built your vector space with.

We can check it for the second example (we will try to prove the linearity in the first component)

$$
\text{LHS}:f(\alpha x + \beta y, z) = (\alpha x + \beta y, z, \alpha xz + \beta yz)
$$

$$
\text{RHS}:\alpha f(x,z) + \beta f(y, z) = \alpha (x, z, xz) + \beta(y,z, yz)
$$

So we see, that $f$ is not linear (LHS contains $z$ in the middle coordinate, while RHS $(\alpha + \beta)z$, which generally does not equal).

And I like the way my professor put it: *"Analysis starts when you have derivative".*

*Last note*

I think it is worth to mention, that we often discuss the examples of finite dimension, but also very small (e.g. $\dim V \leq 5$), or spaces with infinite dimension, e.g.

$$
\mathcal{l}^p = \{\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty: \sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert x_k \vert^p < \infty\}
$$

I was then very surprised, when in *Neural networks* we used vector spaces with $\dim V \approx 5000$ and we constructed systems

$$
f: 5000 \to 500 \to 50 \to \{0,1\},
$$

where 5000, 500, 50 are the dimension of corresponding spaces.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that was fairly obvious (making it more difficult in my head). Thanks for the example, that helped.

Comment: Glad it helped. That is one very interesting property of mathematics - at least I have experienced it many times, so far. Something appears to be difficult, not intuitive, but after you understand it, it seems to be easy. It is sometimes hard, because it lacks the feel of _victory/happiness_ when you accomplish it. Fortunately, it is not the case all the time, and it is good to learn to be happy even when you understand something which looks obvious afterwards. I guess, whole new world opens to you.

Answer (score 0):

Such things are possible even in linear algebra.  For example, the linear map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by action on the standard basis $e_1\mapsto 1$ and $e_2\mapsto -1$ is just such a map.  In linear algebra, these types of maps have certain properties in terms of the dimension of the kernel and image of the map.  This kind of map is not uncommon in other branches of mathematics as well (e.g. set theory and topology), but there the properties tend to be a bit less obvious.